# Authentication Error - googlesheet package - R

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am trying to use `googlesheets` package by initiating as below:

```
install.packages("googlesheets")
library(googlesheets)
gs_auth()
```

which gives me the following message:

```
Click "ok" button in two steps for authorization .
**Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
 Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds**
```

Even when it shows "Authentication complete", nothing is initiated because
every `gs_xxx()` function return back to the first step.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem with `googlesheets` 0.3.0 and R 3.4.3. Perhaps a session info?

Comment: R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- vs -- googlesheets_0.3.0   Maybe its the reason of the error ? (i use Windows 7 x86_64)(Thankyou your reply Kim)